# merge row with next row in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, rows

I have a dataframe in pandas which contains multiple columns. I want to merge every row with the next row.
Example:

input dataframe:

```
A   B   C
a1  a2  a3
b1  b2  b3
c1  c1  c3
d1  d2  d3
```

output dataframe:

```
A1   B1   C1  A2   B2   C2
a1   a2   a3  b1   b2   b3
b1   b2   b3  c1   c2   c3
c1   c2   c3  d1   d2   d3
d1   d2   d3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The solusion I came up with was copying the original dataframe, changing the index to be index - 1, and then merging the two data frames by index.
Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), for new columns names [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) is useful:

```
df1 = df.add_suffix('1').join(df.shift(-1).add_suffix('2'))
```

---

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.add_suffix('1'), df.shift(-1).add_suffix('2')], axis=1)
```

---

```
df1 = df.add_suffix('1').assign(**df.shift(-1).add_suffix('2'))


print (df1)
   A1  B1  C1   A2   B2   C2
0  a1  a2  a3   b1   b2   b3
1  b1  b2  b3   c1   c1   c3
2  c1  c1  c3   d1   d2   d3
3  d1  d2  d3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
In [204]: pd.concat([df.add_suffix(1), df[1:].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix(2)],
                    axis=1)
Out[204]:
   A1  B1  C1   A2   B2   C2
0  a1  a2  a3   b1   b2   b3
1  b1  b2  b3   c1   c1   c3
2  c1  c1  c3   d1   d2   d3
3  d1  d2  d3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

And, extend it to generic use

```
In [206]: N = 3   # Say 3 more times

In [207]: pd.concat([df.add_suffix(1)] + 
                    [df[x+1:].reset_index(drop=True).add_suffix(x+2)
                     for x in range(N)], axis=1)
Out[207]:
   A1  B1  C1   A2   B2   C2   A3   B3   C3   A4   B4   C4
0  a1  a2  a3   b1   b2   b3   c1   c1   c3   d1   d2   d3
1  b1  b2  b3   c1   c1   c3   d1   d2   d3  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  c1  c1  c3   d1   d2   d3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  d1  d2  d3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```