# How to modify using pandas to cell merge

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This original data
Before:

```
| 0 | name | age | sex |
| 1 | jan  | 30  | M  |
| 2 | job | address |
| 3 | yes | 42424   | 
| 4 | name| age | sex |
| 5 | jan |  30 |  M  |
| 6 | job | address |
| 7 | yes | 42424   | 
| 8 | name| age | sex |
| 9 | jan |  30 |  M  |
|10 | job | address |
|11 | yes | 42424   |
```

After:

```
| 0 | name | age | sex | job | address |
| 1 | jan  | 30  |  M  | yes | 42424   |
| 2 | jan  | 30  |  M  | yes | 42424   |
| 3 | jan  | 30  |  M  | yes | 42424   |
```

I want to change the cells using the Python code with the help of pandas. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to accomplish using your 'before' and getting your 'after' as an input, check this out: [merge row with next row in dataframe pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450259/merge-row-with-next-row-in-dataframe-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just slice your df and `concat` if the format is always the same:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({' name ': {0: 'jan', 1: 'job', 2: 'yes', 3: 'name', 4: 'jan', 5: 'job', 6: 'yes', 7: 'name', 8: 'jan', 9: 'job', 10: 'yes'},
                   ' age ': {0: '30', 1: 'address', 2: '42424', 3: 'age', 4: '30', 5: 'address', 6: '42424', 7: 'age', 8: '30', 9: 'address', 10: '42424'},
                   ' sex ': {0: 'M', 1: nan, 2: '', 3: 'sex', 4: 'M', 5: nan, 6: '', 7: 'sex', 8: 'M', 9: nan, 10: ''}})

new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[::4].reset_index(drop=True),
                    df.iloc[2::4,:2].reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)

new_df.columns = ["name","age","sex","job","address"]

print (new_df)

#
  name age sex  job address
0  jan  30   M  yes   42424
1  jan  30   M  yes   42424
2  jan  30   M  yes   42424
```